# Does this integral exist as improper Riemann integral?

Tags: real-analysis, analysis, improper-integrals, riemann-integration

$\int xdx$ as upper bound goes to infinity and lower bound goes to negative infinity.

$\int xdx$ as the bounds go to finite b and -b exists and is always equal to 0. Does that mean that this integral exists as an improper integral?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

No. You have shown that if it exists then it is equal to $0$. But in order for the integral to exist, it must be well-defined however you take the limit; and if you take the upper limit to infinity twice as fast as you take the lower limit, you'll get the answer $\infty$, which is definitely not $0$.

Comment: To follow up: the OP has shown that the integral exists in the sense of the "Cauchy principal value". This is a useful notion sometimes, but it is weaker than improper Riemann integration (in the sense that having an integral exist in the sense of Cauchy PV doesn't allow you to do as much stuff with it as a true improper Riemann integral).